# Ruby GraphViz Binary Tree Record

Tags: ruby, binary-tree, graphviz

I'm using the [ruby-graphviz](http://github.com/glejeune/Ruby-Graphviz) gem and I'm trying to draw binary trees. I'd like to use the [record shape](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html) so that each node can have a left, middle, and right field and, thus, if there are two edges leaving a node, the left and right edges can be distinguished.

I tried specifying the field by concatenating the field name like this: `@node1.name + ":left"` But that did not work. What is the correct way of specifying the field?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'graphviz'

@graph = GraphViz.new( :G, :type => :digraph )

@node1 = @graph.add_node("1", 
  "shape" => "record", 
  "label" => "<left>|<f1> 1|<right>" )

@node2 = @graph.add_node("2", 
  "shape" => "record", 
  "label" => "<left>|<f1> 2|<right>" )

@graph.add_edge(@node1.name + ":left", @node2)

# generate a random filename
filename = "/tmp/#{(0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join}.png"
@graph.output( :png => filename )
exec "open #{filename}"
```

Answer (score 2):

in the GraphViz documentation, you can see that a node ID must not begin with a digit. So if you change your code and replace the two nodes names (1 and 2) by any other ID beginning by a letter or an underscore, it works :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'graphviz'

@graph = GraphViz.new( :G, :type => :digraph )

@node1 = @graph.add_node("A1", 
  "shape" => "record", 
  "label" => "<left>|<f1> 1|<right>" )

@node2 = @graph.add_node("A2", 
  "shape" => "record", 
  "label" => "<left>|<f1> 2|<right>" )

@graph.add_edge(@node1.name + ":left", @node2)

# generate a random filename
filename = "/tmp/#{(0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join}.png"
@graph.output( :png => filename )
exec "open #{filename}"
```

Maybe i need to replace GraphViz::Node#name by GraphViz::Node#id

Greg

Comment: Oups ! I'm wrong... The ID can begin with a digit if the ID is ONLY a number (matching [-]?(.[0-9]+ | [0-9]+(.[0-9]*)?) ) I just made a correction in the lib ! It's a bug !

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
@graph.add_edge(@node1, @node2, :tailport => "left")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your way of specifying node and field was wrong. Rather you should do:

```
@graph.add_edge({@node1.name=>"left"}, @node2)
```

Refer to the example coming with its source code at:
https://github.com/glejeune/Ruby-Graphviz/blob/master/examples/sample07.rb